# MLflow change experiment id

Tags: python, machine-learning, mlflow

I am unable to change the experiment id of a MLflow experiment.

Currently, I am running the following code to create an experiment before logging:

```
mlflow.set_experiment(experiment_name="my_model")

with mlflow.start_run():
   #train model
```

Doing so allows me to create a new experiment, but the experiment id will always be 1.

The yaml file created looks like this:

```
artifact_location: file:///project/src/mlruns/1
experiment_id: '1'
lifecycle_stage: active
name: my_model
```

I have tried to look at the MLflow documentation, but I cannot find examples or functions where the experiment id is altered.

I would greatly appreciate any help or tips with this.

Comment: What's the reason that you need to set the experiment id?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be possible via apis

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should call you `experiment_id` in the `start_run()`:

```
mlflow.set_experiment("experiment name")
experiment = mlflow.get_experiment_by_name("experiment name")

with mlflow.start_run(experiment_id=experiment.experiment_id):
     # train model
```

**Note**: If you use `set_tracking_uri()`, you should `set_experiment()` after that.

Comment: This changes the experiment name. However it would still create an integer as experiment_id.

Answer (score 0):

mlflow has **unique id per experiment**, if you want **new exp id** you have to **set new experiment name**

```
with mlflow.start_run(mlflow.set_experiment("new_experiment"),run_name='train') as run :
   #train model
```

run_name can be anything which you like ,meaningful to you

if you want to change exp id of your `experiment_name="my_model"` take a back up and
delete the artifact and the database which store the mapping of it and re run your module. but before delete make sure you see some other exp on ml UI.